# Warning: File for type '[Insert class here]' created in the last round will not be subject to annotation processing

Tags: java, java-7

I switched an existing code base to Java 7 and I keep getting this warning:

```
warning: File for type '[Insert class here]' created in the last round 
  will not be subject to annotation processing.
```

A quick search reveals that no one has hit this warning.

It's not documented in the javac compiler source either:

From OpenJDK\langtools\src\share\classes\com\sun\tools\javac\processing\JavacFiler.java

```
private JavaFileObject createSourceOrClassFile(boolean isSourceFile, String name) throws IOException {
    checkNameAndExistence(name, isSourceFile);
    Location loc = (isSourceFile ? SOURCE_OUTPUT : CLASS_OUTPUT);
    JavaFileObject.Kind kind = (isSourceFile ?
                                JavaFileObject.Kind.SOURCE :
                                JavaFileObject.Kind.CLASS);

    JavaFileObject fileObject =
        fileManager.getJavaFileForOutput(loc, name, kind, null);
    checkFileReopening(fileObject, true);

    if (lastRound) // <-------------------------------TRIGGERS WARNING
        log.warning("proc.file.create.last.round", name);

    if (isSourceFile)
        aggregateGeneratedSourceNames.add(name);
    else
        aggregateGeneratedClassNames.add(name);
    openTypeNames.add(name);

    return new FilerOutputJavaFileObject(name, fileObject);
}
```

What does this mean and what steps can I take to clear this warning?

Thanks.

Comment: When I read this question, I initially thought it was because you failed to close a file.  To test this, I created a simple processor that created, wrote to, but did not close a file.  I ran it.  It gave a similar but different warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [OpenJDK test case](http://code.google.com/p/jsr308-langtools/source/browse/test/tools/javac/diags/examples/ProcFileCreateLastRound) this warning produced because processor uses "processingOver()" to write new file exactly at last round.

```
public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> elems, RoundEnvironment renv) {
        if (renv.processingOver()) { // Write only at last round
            Filer filer = processingEnv.getFiler();
            Messager messager = processingEnv.getMessager();
            try {
                JavaFileObject fo = filer.createSourceFile("Gen");
                Writer out = fo.openWriter();
                out.write("class Gen { }");
                out.close();
                messager.printMessage(Diagnostic.Kind.NOTE, "File 'Gen' created");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                messager.printMessage(Diagnostic.Kind.ERROR, e.toString());
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

I modified original example code a bit. Added diagnostic note "File 'Gen' created", replaced "*" mask with "org.junit.runner.RunWith" and set return value to "true". Produced compiler log was:

```
Round 1:
input files: {ProcFileCreateLastRound}
annotations: [org.junit.runner.RunWith]
last round: false
Processor AnnoProc matches [org.junit.runner.RunWith] and returns true.
Round 2:
input files: {}
annotations: []
last round: true
Note: File 'Gen' created
Compilation completed successfully with 1 warning
0 errors
1 warning
Warning: File for type 'Gen' created in the last round will not be subject to annotation processing.
```

If we remove my custom note from log, it's hard to tell that file 'Gen' was actually created on 'Round 2' - last round. So, basic advice applies: if in doubt - add more logs.

---

Where is also a little bit of useful info on this page:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javac.html

Read section about "ANNOTATION PROCESSING" and try to get more info with compiler options:
**-XprintProcessorInfo**
Print information about which annotations a processor is asked to process.
**-XprintRounds** Print information about initial and subsequent annotation processing rounds.

Comment: Yup, did that before I asked the question (probably should have put it in the info above). It didn't seem to yield anything useful. Once it got to the last round, it said that there were no further input files and then send the warnings.

Comment: Could you isolate minimal test case which produces this warning? Maybe with help of compiler options above. I found one test case in OpenJDK sources: folder "openjdk\langtools\test\tools\javac\diags\examples\ProcFileCreateLastRound" [link to same folder on google code](http://code.google.com/p/jsr308-langtools/source/browse/test/tools/javac/diags/examples/ProcFileCreateLastRound/?name=jdk7-b135). But I still couldn't understand why warning was placed in that place.

Comment: I added to my original answer possible cause of your problem. If it's something else, then I couldn't tell more until I see test case.

Comment: This is likely the one. There was some areas where we check to see if processing is over before emitting files, likely due to FilerExceptions of opening the same file more than once.

Answer (score 5):

The warning

> warning: File for type '[Insert class here]' created in the last round
>   will not be subject to annotation processing

means that your were running an annotation processor creating a new class or source file using a javax.annotation.processing.Filer implementation (provided through the javax.annotation.processing.ProcessingEnvironment) although the processing tool already decided its "in the last round".

This may be problem (and thus the warning) because the generated file itself may contain annotations being ignored by the annotation processor (because it is not going to do a further round).

The above ought to answer the first part of your question

> What does this mean and what steps can I take to clear this warning?

(you figured this out already by yourself, didn't you :-))

What possible steps to take? Check your annotation processors:

1) Do you really have to use filer.createClassFile / filer.createSourceFile on the very last round of the annotaion processor? Usually one uses the filer object inside of a code block like

```
for (TypeElement annotation : annotations) {
...
}
```

(in method process). This ensures that the annotation processor will not be in its last round (the last round always being the one having an empty set of annotations).

2) If you really can't avoid writing your generated files in the last round and these files are source files, trick the annotation processor and use the method "createResource" of the filer object (take "SOURCE_OUTPUT" as location).

Comment: Another alternative approach if we can't avoid writing in the last round is to obtain the JavaFileWriter in an earlier round but not to actually write to it until the last round.

Answer (score 0):

I poked around the java 7 compiler options and I found this:

**-implicit:{class,none}**
    Controls the generation of class files for implicitly loaded source files. To automatically generate class files, use -implicit:class. To suppress class file generation, use -implicit:none. If this option is not specified, the default is to automatically generate class files. In this case, the compiler will issue a warning if any such class files are generated when also doing annotation processing. The warning will not be issued if this option is set explicitly. See Searching For Types.

[Source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javac.html)

Can you try and implicitly declare the class file.

Comment: The issue here is with annotation processing, not with class generation. This particular codebase depends on class generation. Specifiying -implicit:none actually breaks the build since the classes aren't generated. -implicit:class has no effect on the warning.